# Show that the following pairs of sets have the same cardinality by giving explicit bijections between them

Tags: cardinals

Show that the following pairs of sets have the same cardinality by giving explicit bijections between them:

(a) $M_{2×2}(\mathbb C)$ and $\mathbb R$8

(b) $(0,1)$ and $(−1,+\infty)$

(c) The sets $\{z\in\mathbb C \mid 0<|z|<1,\ 0<\arg(z)<\frac{\pi}4\}\quad\text{ and }\\\{z\in\mathbb C \mid 0<|z|<2,\ \Re(z)<0,\ \Im(z)>0\}$

How would I find the bijections between these sets that have to same cardinality? Thanks.

Comment: for b you can use something like an $\tan$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(a) $M_{2x2}(\mathbb C)\equiv \mathbb C^4\equiv\mathbb R^8$ and $\mathbb R^n$ equipotent to $\mathbb R$ but explicit bijection is not straightforward.

(b) $(0,1)\overset{\frac 1x}{\longmapsto}(1,+\infty)\overset{x-2}{\longmapsto}(-1,+\infty)$

(c) $\{0<|z|<1,0<\theta<\frac{\pi}4\}\overset{z^2}{\longmapsto}\{0<|z|<1,0<\theta<\frac{\pi}2\}\overset{iz}{\longmapsto}\{0<|z|<1,\frac{\pi}2<\theta<\pi\}\overset{2z}{\longmapsto}\{0<|z|<2,\Re(z)<0,\Im(z)>0\}$

Comment: Can you explain your answer for (a) please?

Comment: @BobParker A complex $2\times 2$ matrix is basically $4$ complex numbers. And a complex number is basically $2$ reals. So a complex $2\times 2$ matrix can be represented by $8$ reals coefficients.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. But in order to show an explicit bijection, that explanation wouldn't suffice, right?

Comment: just show that $(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h)\mapsto\begin{bmatrix}a+ib & c+id \\ e+if & g+ih\end{bmatrix}$ is a bijection, should not be too hard. i.e. given $z=a+ib$ then $a=\frac{z+\bar z}2$ and $b=\frac{z-\bar z}2$

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. So there are essentially two primary bijections that apply to all 8 real numbers?

Comment: Yes, you've got it.

Comment: Sorry, but how did you determine the Arg(z) and figure out the bijections for (c)?

Comment: $\Re(z)<0,\Im(z)>0$ is the second quadrant, so $\theta\in]\frac{\pi}2,\pi[$. Multiplying by $i$ is a rotation of $\perp$ angle and $z^2$ on the unit circle double the angle $(e^{i\theta})^2=e^{i2\theta}$. Finally $2z$ takes care of the amplitude. Draw a picture of the two angular sectors, you'll understand how to convert one in the other.

Answer (score 0):

For $(a)$, I reckon what's fundamental is that you find a bijection between $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$. **Hint:** try to use digits of the decimal expansion!

For $(b)$, you can try to modify functions like $\tan(x)$ or $\frac1x$.

For $(c)$, try to draw the sets. The bijection should be pretty obvious once you've pictured them.

Answer (score -1):

(B) set (0'1) have cardinality C and Also (1, infinite) cardinality C
Using result same cardinality of the set equivalent
Impiles (0'1)~(1'infinite)
Implis that is bijective
Define map:
F(x)=1/x